# while (!scannerObject.hasNext(patternObject)) works for only one iteration

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

**The problem**

I only get one successful iteration from a `while` loop that is controlled by a `hasNext(Pattern pattern)` condition. I try to 'clear' the input stream (?) with `.next()` but unsuccessfully.

**The behaviour**

If I enter invalid input the first time, seemingly valid subsequent input continues to execute the `System.out.print("You did not enter a valid size. Try again: ")` line. But this line should only execute if `Scanner getPizzaSize` does not have valid input.

If instead I enter valid input the first time, it works and the program advances, but when `while (orderingPizza)` comes around for a second iteration all input to `getPizzaSize` (valid or not) executes `System.out.print("You did not enter a valid size. Try again: ")` line.

I only get one successful iteration from my `!getPizzaSize.hasNext(validPizzaSizes)` loop:

```
Please place the order for your pizza.
Size (s = small, l = large, f = family): s
Please place the order for your pizza.
Size (s = small, l = large, f = family): s
You did not enter a valid size. Try again:
```

I should get:

```
Please place the order for your pizza.
Size (s = small, l = large, f = family): s
Please place the order for your pizza.
Size (s = small, l = large, f = family): s
Please place the order for your pizza.
Size (s = small, l = large, f = family):
```

(The regular expression I am using should match: *s, S, l, L, f, F*. This link might be to test results: https://regexr.com/5gdla.)

**A solution**

If I redeclare `Scanner getPizzaSize` in the `.hasNext(Pattern pattern)` loop, the loop behaves as expected:

1. invalid inputs are followed by `You did not enter valid input . . . try again`; and
2. a valid input advances through the program

**What I want to understand**

There seems to be an issue with how I am reading in from `getPizzaSize` with `.next()`. But I don't know what the issue is. Is it my regular expression? Something about the nature of `.next()` in combination with `.hasNext(Pattern pattern)`? For integer inputs, `.hasNextInt()` and `.next()` work perfectly.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PizzaOrder{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialise Scanner object.
        Scanner getPizzaSize = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Initialise Pattern object for detecting valid size input.
        Pattern validPizzaSizes = Pattern.compile("^[slf]$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        while (true) {
            // Ask for pizza size.
            System.out.print("Please place the order for your pizza.\n" +
                    "Size (s = small, l = large, f = family): ");
            // Validate size input.
            while (!getPizzaSize.hasNext(validPizzaSizes)) {
                System.out.print("You did not enter a valid size. Try again: ");
                getPizzaSize.next();
            }
            // Set pizza size.
            String pizzaSize = getPizzaSize.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is saying that "s", "l" or "f" must be the start and the end of string, as indicated by the `^` and `$` anchors. However, as far as the scanner is concerned, the second `s` you entered is not at the start of the string. It's *after* the first `s` you entered (probably also separated by a line separator)!

You should not use the `^` anchor. Your regex should just be:

```
[slf]$
```

This also explains why creating a new scanner works. Because the new scanner doesn't know about the previous `s` that you entered.

Comment: I didn't realise previous input was still existing in a string in some way. Am I literally building a bigger and bigger string  in memory each time I use the Scanner? Will I run out of memory if I receive enough orders?

Comment: @WarrenTheRabbit I didn't know that until I inspected the `Scanner` object in the debugger either! The characters are stored in an array called `buf`, so I'm guessing the inner logic of `Scanner` will clear it once it is full.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what it means to inspect the `Scanner` in the debugger!  How did you do that? I need to sleep but I want to try inspecting in the debugger next time I have a problem.

If you have some suggestions, wonderful. I'll read them in the morning. If not, not a problem. I appreciate the time you already gave and your help!

Comment: @WarrenTheRabbit Just look up how to use the debugger in whatever IDE you are using. There are plenty of tutorials around.