# Java Scanner hasNext() method failing to match any input

Tags: java, regex, pdfbox

I am writing a parsing program and I would like to utilize a regular expression to do some matching work. I am looking specifically for lines in a pdf which contain the substring "RPR". The relevant code is the following:

```
while(parser.hasNext()){
   if(parser.hasNext("^.*RPR.*$")){
      //Do something.
   }
   else{
      //Do something.
   }
}
```

Specifically the regular expression I constructed is "^.*RPR.*$". I have tried variations of this but this was the best one I came up with. The parser object is a scanner object which is scanning the block of text output by the PDFTextStripper. The delimiter is set to "\n".

For example one of the lines of text I am trying to match to is the following.

"Walls RPR MAINT: nail holes"

But when I run the comparison with the above regular expression I get a false test. Please understand that if I hard code the string in another test program the test works fine but when I run the application with the text extracted from a PDF I get a negative result and I have no idea why I would be getting a different result in either case. I'm literally printing the lines of text to the console then copying and pasting them into the test program.

Things to note:

1. The String object I am parsing is the text from a pdf document stripped using a PDFTextStripper object from PDFBox.
2. I have printed the String I am parsing to make sure that there are lines containing an instance of RPR and there are tons of them.
3. I know that I can also use the String classes .contains method but utilizing a regular expression will be better because my application is going to need to be expanded in the future.
4. When I copy the output to a temporary program and run it against my expression I get a matching result. This is the most frustrating aspect and why I am at a loss for what to try next.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does your code not work? Please show a [mcve], and include the inputs, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: It's hard to guess where things go wrong. Maybe this sample helps https://ideone.com/UtTT7h

Comment: @Sweeper hopefully my edits explain why a minimal reproducible example is unfeasible. If I hard code the lines I am testing of which I give an example the expression texts positive. However, when I iterate line by line over the entire block which is generated from a pdf the expression tests negative.

Comment: @wp78de even though the documentation for the Scanner class says that your suggestion has precisely the same behavior as the sample I provided I tried it out on my file anyway and I'm still getting negative tests.

Comment: Maybe an encoding problem? Have you checked the strings in question in a debugger?

Comment: A wild guess: might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64874568/5133585). Is the desired line the _first line_ in the string extracted from the PDF? If not, then it is expected that your code does not work. `^` matches the start of string, not start of line. Try creating a `Pattern` with the multiline option.

Comment: Have you looked at the pdfbox text stripper output in detail? There might be an extra space (regular, non-breaking, zero-width, ... there are many kinds of spaces) or some other unexpected character there which your re does not match...

Comment: *"I'm literally printing the lines of text to the console then copying and pasting them into the test program."* - that can be lossy, console output does not show everything. Write to and read from a file, making sure you use the same unicode encoding. And inspect the file in a hex viewer.

Comment: If `"(?s)^.*RPR.*$"` does not work, the problem is with the code.